# Request limit and lapply

Tags: r, lapply, ncbi, rentrez

I want to make thousands of entrez requests. I know that you are not allowed to make more than 3 requests per second unless you have an API key. The rentrez introduction says that rentrez enforces this limit.

I just want to make sure that NCBI does not block me, so the performance is not the issue here.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rentrez/vignettes/rentrez_tutorial.html

But what if I combine `lapply()` with `entrez_search()`?

```
authors <- c("Uhelski ML", "Manjavachi MN")
authors_pubs <- lapply(authors, function(x) entrez_search(db = "pubmed",term = paste0(x, "[AUTH]"), use_history = TRUE))
```

Does rentrez still enforces the request limit in this case or do I have to introduce stops into my code?

Comment: What happens when you run the above code?

Comment: It returns a list with a entrez_search result for each author.

Comment: If any API provider is putting restriction on `rate limit`, you need to respect that. You can do that in your code by introducing some form of `sleep`?

Comment: Yes, if I have to I would use Sys.sleep(0.4). The question is do I have to? If rentrez already does this, I would just slow down the code by introducing stops.

Comment: The answer is yes, you need to add the Sys.sleep function.  `lapply` is just a compact loop, thus you are calling the `entrez_search` many many times.

Comment: OK, but then the question is: What does the vignette mean when it states that rentrez enforces the limit?